# What does "age: Integer{0<=age<=150}" mean in UML Diagram?

Tags: c#, uml

I want to write a C# code from UML Diagram as shown below. However, I come across this attribute "age: Integer{0<=age<=150}". I will circle for you. May I know what it means? and How can we convert it to C# code?
[image: C#]

Comment: Just a mention, the closing is curly bracket, not a parenthesis. It is shown correctly in the diagram, but you mistyped it in your question. The answers has already been provided so I'll just limit my input to this comment and upvotes ;-)

Comment: @Ister You could have simply fixed it :-)

Comment: @qwerty_so I keep forgetting I can :-D Thanks for reminding me (and fixing as I suppose) ;-)

Answer (score 6):

It means the minimum limit of age is 0 and maximum is 150.
A person in the system should not have a negative age or an age more than 150 years.

You can implement this by having a condition to check the age value when a user enter it to the system.

Comment: Excellent. The enforcement should however not be limited to the user interface. Since it’s a private property, the constraint is a class invariant that should preferably be guaranteed or enforced by all the operations of the class, in particular setData().

Answer (score 3):

This is called a *constraint* and can be recognized by the surrounding curly brackets. You can write either clear text, use a mathematical formula or write OCL (not for the faint hearted and probably too lenghty in any case here).

See p. 35 of UML 2.5:

> A Constraint is an assertion that indicates a restriction that must be satisfied by any valid realization of the model containing the Constraint. A Constraint is attached to a set of constrainedElements, and it represents additional semantic information about those Elements.
> [...]
>
> `<constraint> ::= ‘{‘ [ <name> ‘:’ ] <boolean-expression> ‘ }’`

Comment: Indeed! In this case, let’s assume the mathematical formula, since comparators in OCL are binary operations for integers, strings and reals, but not for booleans (which would make the expression inconsistent in view of operator precedence)